# How to specify a function as the default of a scriptblock parameter in a PowerShell function?

Tags: function, powershell, parameters, block, defaults

Given these powershell functions where foo takes a scriptblock as parameter:

```
function bar($name)
{
    "Hello World $name"
}

function foo([scriptblock]$fun={})
{
    &$fun "Bart"
}
```

Is it possible to specify the function bar as default for $fun instead of {} in function foo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. For example, this way works for passing a function in:

```
foo ((get-command bar).scriptblock)
```

In your case it prints

```
Hello World Bart
```

Thus, in order to use it as the default parameter:

```
function foo([scriptblock]$fun=(get-command bar).scriptblock)
{
    &$fun "Bart"
}
```

Now just calling

```
foo
```

gets the same result.

Comment: Thanks! Eventually I found that I could use $fun=${Function:\bar} but I'm not quite sure which alternative is more intention revealing.

Comment: Ah, this is an interesting find. It is shorter, at least, or maybe even faster. I'll play with it a little.

Comment: Yes, it is also faster. It is useful to know. I can update my answer with this extra option for completeness or you may update your question with this useful information.